# Saben como agregar un JTable a un JFrame

Tags: java

Quiero agregar un JTable a un JFrame a puro código sin la herramienta Desing de NetBeans

Comment: ¿Hay alguna razón por la que no quieras usar las herramientas de diseño de NetBeans? Si es porque usas eclipse, este tiene un plugin para Swing, a parte de eso, lo digo porque es mucho más sencillo agregarlo desde ahí ya que te ahorrará tiempo y siempre puedes quitarle cosas desde código después, de todas formas, en este enlace podrás ver un ejemplo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13307743/displaying-jtable-in-jframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma más sencilla es siguiendo estos pasos :

1. Crear un Arreglo de tipo `Object` para el valor mostrado en la cabecera de las `columnas`
2. Crear un Arreglo `2D` de tipo `Object` para los valores a mostrar en el `JTable`
3. Creas tu `JTable` pasando le por parámetro al constructor los dos Arreglos creados anteriormente
4. Lo agregas al `JFrame` u Otro `contenedor`

   ```
   Object[] nombrecolumnas = {"Nombre", "Apellido", "Edad"};
   Object[][] datos ={{"Nombre1", "Apellido1", 22},{"Nombre2", "Apellido2", 4}};
   tabla = new JTable(datos,nombrecolumnas);
   Jframe.add(tabla);
   ```